# Kafka Streams Warning for unsubscribed topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

In my kafka streams application, I have subscribed to a list of topics, lets say ( Topic1, Topic2, Topic3 ).  Overall, broker has more than 3 topics(100s) and other stream applications are using those topics.

In my application ( which is consuming Topic1, Topic2 & Topic3), I keep on seeing the WARNing related to other topics also.

```
14:02:33.910 478517 [Application-468d913c-bca0-4ad9-baec-5b51ffa597d2-StreamThread-4] WARN  o.a.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=Application-468d913c-bca0-4ad9-baec-5b51ffa597d2-StreamThread-4-consumer, groupId=Application] 1389 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [Topic4, Topic5, Topic6, Topic7, ..., Topic8-Link-Store-changelog-5 ]
```

the message is printed by following kafka code
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/NetworkClient.java

```
@Override
        public void handleSuccessfulResponse(RequestHeader requestHeader, long now, MetadataResponse response) {
            // If any partition has leader with missing listeners, log up to ten of these partitions
            // for diagnosing broker configuration issues.
            // This could be a transient issue if listeners were added dynamically to brokers.
            List<TopicPartition> missingListenerPartitions = response.topicMetadata().stream().flatMap(topicMetadata ->
                topicMetadata.partitionMetadata().stream()
                    .filter(partitionMetadata -> partitionMetadata.error() == Errors.LISTENER_NOT_FOUND)
                    .map(partitionMetadata -> new TopicPartition(topicMetadata.topic(), partitionMetadata.partition())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
            if (!missingListenerPartitions.isEmpty()) {
                int count = missingListenerPartitions.size();
                log.warn("{} partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including {}",
                        count, missingListenerPartitions.subList(0, Math.min(10, count)));
            }
```

Is this expected ? Why are these warning messages are posted in my application ?

Answer (score 0):

Note

> This could be a transient issue if listeners were added dynamically to brokers

In any case, this would indicate an issue with the `listeners` property defined on the brokers.

For example, you've connected to `PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092`, but the server actually starts with `PLAINTEXT_SASL://`